# (Coleman QFT notes) Physical vacuum has no one-meson content?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, vacuum, mesons

I'm looking at Lecture 14 in Coleman's QFT notes. In defining the renormalized field $\phi'(x)$ corresponding to the meson field $\phi(x)$, Coleman notes first that \begin{equation*}
\langle k | \phi(x) | 0_P \rangle = e^{ikx} \langle k | \phi(0) | 0_P \rangle \equiv e^{ikx} Z_3^{1/2}.
\end{equation*}
Here $| 0_P \rangle$ denotes the full/physical vacuum. This is generally different from the bare vacuum $|0 \rangle$ of the free theory, defines the $0$-particle sector of the Fock space. Likewise $| k \rangle$ is a one-meson momentum eigenstate (relativistically normalized, but that's orthogonal to my question). He then defines the renormalized field \begin{equation*}
\phi'(x) \equiv Z^{-1/2}_3 [\phi(x) - \langle 0_P | \phi(x) | 0_P \rangle ]
\end{equation*}
and says that this new field satisfies \begin{equation*}
\langle k | \phi'(x) | 0_P \rangle = e^{ikx}.
\end{equation*}
It seems to me that this only holds if we assume $\langle k | 0_P \rangle = 0$. But from the Fock space construction, any state other than multiples of the bare vacuum $| 0 \rangle$ must have some $n$-particle content for $n \geq 1$, and we know in general that $| 0_P \rangle$ is not simply related to $| 0 \rangle$, so it's not clear why $\langle k | 0_P \rangle = 0$ should be true.

Comment: I don't think this is just a typo. Coleman writes $\phi'(x) = Z_3^{-1/2}[\phi(x) - \langle 0_P | \phi(x) | 0_P \rangle$ in several other places, and in later sections assumes again that $\langle k | 0_P \rangle = 0$. He does this, for example, when he inserts a complete set of states to compute the Kallen-Lehmann spectral representation.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone was wondering, here is the resolution: as all texts make clear, when we move from an exactly solvable to an interacting / "full" / "physical" Hamiltonian, this changes the definition of the vacuum, leading to the notion of a bare vacuum \begin{equation*}
H_0 |0 \rangle = 0
\end{equation*}
versus physical vacuum.\begin{equation*}
H |0 \rangle_P = 0
\end{equation*} The subtler point is that this definition also changes the definition of a one-meson state. This isn't so clear if you think of a meson as the result of applying a creation operator to the bare vacuum (this turns out to be a bad definition), but is quite clear if you think of one-particle states in terms of irreps, since changing the Hamiltonian changes the relevant representation of the Lorentz group.

In short: just as moving $H_0 \to H$ takes us from the bare to physical vacuum $|0 \rangle \to | 0 \rangle_P$, it also takes us from bare to physical one-particle states $|p> \to |p\rangle_P$ and bare to physical momentum operators $P_0^\mu \to P^\mu$. These new one-particle states satisfy \begin{equation*}
P^\mu |p\rangle_P = p^\mu |p\rangle_P
\end{equation*}
unlike the bare ones which satisfy
\begin{equation*}
P_0^\mu |p\rangle = p^\mu |p\rangle
\end{equation*}
with analogous differences under boost and rotation generators.

Comment: Just a small comment. "This isn't so clear if you think of a meson as the result of applying a creation operator to the bare vacuum (this turns out to be a bad definition)," -- It is an ok definition so long as you only work with a creation or annihilation operator acting asymptotic IN or OUT states. (You can see this play out in the derivation of the LSZ formula, see eg Ch 5 of https://chaosbook.org/FieldTheory/extras/SrednickiQFT03.pdf). But everything else sounds right to me!

Comment: Thanks Andrew! If you wouldn't mind, I actually have a question about exactly what Srednicki discusses in that chapter at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/757920/on-waiting-and-colemans-derivation-of-lsz.