# On "waiting" and Coleman's derivation of LSZ

Tags: quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory

I'm going through the derivation LSZ in Coleman's QFT notes. The math is perfectly clear (or at least I don't mind being handwavy about convergence issues), and I'm happy with the idea that \begin{equation*}
\lim_{t \to \pm \infty} \langle \psi | \phi'^f(t) | 0\rangle = \langle \psi | f \rangle.
\end{equation*}
But I'm unclear about the physical story he's drawing when he extends this to multiparticle. In particular, to interpret the formula \begin{equation*}
\lim_{t \to \pm \infty} \langle \psi | \phi'^{f_2}(t) |  f_1 \rangle
\end{equation*}
Coleman writes the following:

*The handwaving requires we picture this in position space. Because $F_1$ and $F_2$ describe packets headed in different directions if you wait long enough (go back far enough) the two wave packets will be widely separated in position. Then the application of $\phi′^{f_2} (t)$ to $|f_1\rangle$ is for all purposes to an observer near the $f_2$ packet, like an application of $\phi′^{f_2} (t)$ to the vacuum.*

But I don't think the limits $\lim_{t \to \pm \infty}$ having anything to do with waiting (or moving into the past). The operator $\phi'^{f_2}(t)$ of course depends on the parameter $t$, but this isn't a physical time dependence (or more explicitly, $\phi'^{f_2}$ isn't some observable changing with time a la Heisenberg picture), so I'm not sure how the intuitive notion of "waiting" corresponds to applying $\phi'^{f_2}(t)$ for large $t$.

If it helps, my working definition of an out state (which is the whole point of this discussion) comes from Weinberg \begin{equation*}
e^{i H t} | \alpha \rangle^{out} \approx e^{i H_0 t} |\alpha \rangle \ \ \ (t \to \infty)
\end{equation*}
(and similarly for in states) and I'm trying to understand why, according to Coleman, \begin{equation*}
\lim_{t \to \infty} \langle \psi | \phi'^{f_2}(t) |  f_1 \rangle = \langle \psi | f_1, f_2 \rangle^{out}.
\end{equation*}
Coleman really glosses over this point while discussing other related issues at great length and Srednicki gives basically the same argument, so I imagine I'm misunderstanding something elementary about the argument here.

***Edit for clarity***

When I say that $\phi'^f(t)$ doesn't evolve a la Heisenberg picture, I mean that the operator (reproducing the definition) \begin{equation*}
\phi'^f(t) := i \int d^3 \vec{x} \left[ \phi'(t,\vec{x}) \partial_0 f(t,\vec{x}) - f(t,\vec{x}) \partial_0 \phi'(t,\vec{x}) \right]
\end{equation*}
doesn't satisfy the Heisenberg equation of motion \begin{equation*}
\phi'^f(t) \neq e^{i H t} \phi'^f(0) e^{- i H t}.
\end{equation*}
Of course the renormalized field $\phi'$ does \begin{equation*}
\phi'(t) = e^{i H t} \phi'(0) e^{- i H t}
\end{equation*}
But unless I calculated something wrong, the presence of the $c$-number field $f(t,\vec{x})$ gives $\phi'^f(t)$ a different time evolution that doesn't look like the Heisenberg E.o.M.

Comment: " ′2 isn't some observable changing with time a la Heisenberg picture" -- why not?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! Added further explanation in the body of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we need here is simply a wave packet that spatially localize the wave functions enough in the past/future. Of course, if we define $f(x)$ as a totally general function, this does not satisfy the equation of motion $\phi^f(t)=e^{iHt}\phi^f(0)e^{-iHt}$, but in fact we consider the wave packets as follows:
$$f(t,\mathbf{x})=\int \frac{d^3 p’}{(2\pi)^3 2E_\mathbf{p’}}\Big(e^{-\frac{(\mathbf{p} -\mathbf{p}’)^2}{2\delta^2}}\Big) e^{-iE_\mathbf{p’}t+i\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{x} }$$
Here we assume the Gaussian wave-packets, but in general we can use any localized function instead of Gaussian. Importantly, this wave packet preserves the equation of motion $\phi^f(t)=e^{iHt}\phi^f(0)e^{-iHt}$ because its time dependence is completely same to that of free field without wave packets. Thus, the time evolution of the wave packet occurs in parallel with the time evolution of the field operator, and your concerns will be addressed.